# Microsoft Dynamic CRM customization

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have created new custom entity. Let's say entity_abc.

Now for that entity I have create new record. This entity is display under xyz security role.

Now I have assign xyz security role to pqr and def users.

So pqr user can see that record as well pqr user can also create new record under entity_abc but def user can not edit that record as well as def user can not create new record. System thrown an error. "Access denied."

Thanks in advanced.
Regards,
Vatsal Thakker

Comment: Would need to know more details e.g. do pqr/def have any other roles that impact on abc entity? in order for def to edit a record created by pqr, they need a different priv/accesslevel than pqr needs to create it. def should be able to create a record same as pqr if def and pqr have the same privs. Maybe tell us more?

Comment: Have you checked the trace logs? They will tell you which permission is missing.

Comment: I am very thankful to James and Keerz for your response and valuable time.

Comment: Hello Keerz, There is no any other security roles except xyz to pqr user and def user.

Comment: Hello James, Still I have not checked the trace logs. I will check it then let you know. Thanks for your helpful advice.

Comment: did you create an custom secqurity role ?

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information I think regarding the configuration of your roles and users.

One possibility: have you assigned the security role directly to both users or via their Team?

If the desired role is present on the Team, but not on the individual user record you will likely encounter an issue.